# We are told 2 is a primitive root mod 101. Show that there is no solution to $x^{6} \equiv 2 \bmod 101$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know how to show that there is no solution if we are dealing with $x^{k} \equiv 2 \bmod 101$ where $k$ divides $100$.  I basically arrive at a contradiction whereby the order of $2$ is less than $100$.  But here $k$ does not divide our $p-1$.  Have not taken abstract algebra but should be solvable using elementary number theory.

Comment: If $x^6 \equiv 2 \pmod{101},$ then $(x^3)^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {101}$.

Comment: furthermore, the cubing map is a bijection $\pmod{101}$   because $101 \equiv 2 \pmod 3 $

Comment: Robert, I think I see where you are leading me.  Since 2 is NOT a quadratic residue mod 101, there is no solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Will, I know what a bijection is, but would you mind connecting your comment to the solution for me?  Apologies as it wasn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: Since $(x^3)^2\equiv 2$, $2^{50}\equiv (x^{100})^3\equiv 1\mod 101$ which contradicts the fact that $2$ is a primitive root (and hence has order $100$ modulo $101$).

Comment: Correct, HFM. That is one way to use Robert Shore's hint.

Comment: Then $x^{6n}$ generates all $\mathbb F_{101}^*$ which easily implies an absurde.

Comment: Worth pointing out that no primitive root $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo an odd prime $p$, because if $a\equiv b^2\bmod p$, then $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv b^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$, so $a$ is not a primitive root.

Answer (score 2):

Since $2$ is a primitive root mod $101,$ we have:

(i). If $\gcd (x,101)=1$ then $2^n\equiv x \mod 101$ for some $n.$

(ii). If $2^m\equiv 1 \mod 101$ then $100=\phi(101)$ is a divisor of $m.$

Now $x^6\equiv 2\mod 101$ implies $\gcd (x,101)=1.$

So if $x^6\equiv 2 \mod 101,$ let $x\equiv 2^n\mod 101$ by (i). Then   $2^{6n}\equiv 2 \mod 101$ so  $2^{6n-1}\equiv 1 \mod 101.$ By (ii) this implies $100|(6n-1),$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Since $101$ is prime, WLOG we may consider $1\le x \le 100$. Since $2$ is given to be a primitive root, we know that for each $(1\le y \le 100)$ there exists a unique $(1\le z \le 100)$, such that $2^y \equiv z \bmod 101$.

Therefore, there exists one unique $1\le k \le 100$ such that $2^k \equiv x \bmod 101$, which would imply $2^{6k} \equiv 2 \bmod 101$ for any $x^6 \equiv 2 \bmod 101$

But $2^1 \equiv 2 \bmod 101$, or since $2^{100}\equiv 1 \bmod 101$, $2^{1+100n} \equiv 2 \bmod 101$, which would then require $6k=1+100n$. Since $6k$ and $1+100n$ have different parity, this an impossibility. So the assumption that $\exists x$ such that $x^6 \equiv 2 \bmod 101$ must be wrong.

Comment: It would not require $6k=1$; it would require $6k\equiv 1$ modulo the appropriate modulus, which is a very different thing. Also, your 'forall' statement is on the sloppy side; that should be a 'forall-exists' statement, since as it's written it suggests that e.g. there's a unique solution to $2^5\equiv 4\mod 101$, which is obviously nonsensical. There's the germ of an idea here but you really need to write it up more precisely.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Thanks for calling attention to the glosses in my original answer. I believe I have corrected them, but I would appreciate being informed of any new or further flaws.